# Ecto schema with a tsrange field

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a Postgres table with a [`tsrange` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), and I'd like to include that in my Ecto module's `schema`. I see that [`Postgrex.Range` exists](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/af5800ec978ebb2a319daaa47f183a08bdec550a/lib/postgrex/builtins.ex#L19-L38). I've tried this:

```
schema "clients" do
  field :valid_at, Postgrex.Range
  ...
end
```

But that gives me this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type Postgrex.Range for field :valid_at
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1785: Ecto.Schema.check_type!/3
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1473: Ecto.Schema.__field__/4
```

Any suggestions? I'm using Phoenix 1.3 and the Ecto master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like @TheAnh has the right approach, but here is what actually wound up working for me:

```
defmodule Myapp.TsRange do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type

  def type, do: :tsrange

  def cast(nil),            do: {:ok, nil}
  def cast([lower, upper]), do: {:ok, [lower, upper]}
  def cast(_),              do: :error

  def load(%Postgrex.Range{lower: lower, upper: upper}) do
    lower = lower |> to_datetime
    upper = upper |> to_datetime
    case [lower, upper] do
      [nil, nil]                   -> {:ok, [nil, nil]}
      [{:ok, lower}, {:ok, upper}] -> {:ok, [lower, upper]}
      _ -> :error
    end
  end
  def load(_), do: :error

  def dump([lower, upper]) do
    {:ok, %Postgrex.Range{lower: lower |> from_datetime,
                          upper: upper |> from_datetime,
                          upper_inclusive: false}}
  end
  def dump(_), do: :error

  defp to_datetime(nil), do: nil
  defp to_datetime({{y, m, d}, {h, min, s, ms}}) do
    NaiveDateTime.new(y, m, d, h, min, s, ms)
  end

  defp from_datetime(nil), do: nil
  defp from_datetime(dt) do
    {{dt.year, dt.month, dt.day}, {dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, elem(dt.microsecond, 0)}}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create a custom type for `tsrange` to work with Ecto.

```
defmodule YourApp.TimestampRange do
 @behaviour Ecto.Type

  def type, do: :tsrange

  def cast([lower, upper]) do
    {:ok, [lower, upper]}
  end

  def cast(_), do: :error 

  def load(%Postgrex.Range{lower: lower, upper: upper}) do
    {:ok, [lower, upper]}
  end

  def dump([lower, upper]) do
    {:ok, %Postgrex.Range{lower: lower, upper: upper, upper_inclusive: false}}
  end

  def dump(_), do: :error
end
```

About inclusive boundaries checkout [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)

and then in your app you can use:

```
schema "clients" do
  field :valid_at, YourApp.TimestampRange
  ...
end
```

Comment: You don't really need the first `load` clause here. The second clause will handle the `nil` case exactly the same way.